# handlemessage handler class not working with toast

Tags: android

I am writing a handler and trying to get the Thread name printed in the handlemessage method
the code is as below

```
public class handler extends Activity
{
    EditText et;
    Handler h=new Handler()
    {
    public void handleMessage(Message m)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Thread.currentThread().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.handler);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.handle);
        Thread t=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                int i=0;
                while(i<10)
                {
                    try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }catch(Exception ep){}
                    i++;
                    h.dispatchMessage(h.obtainMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();


    }

}
```

However the app crashes. If i use log.v to print the thread name it works.kindly update why it happens.
thanks
tejinder

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: use runnable to show toast

Comment: why runnable is required to show just a toast message

Comment: it is related to some looper class

Answer (score 1):

in stead of using this sentence:

```
h.dispatchMessage(h.obtainMessage());
```

use this one:

```
h.sendMessage(h.obtainMessage());
```

The crash is because you cannot do any modifications to the UI from any thread other than the MAIN, by calling dispatchMessage is just like calling directly the handleMessage of the handler from the thread you are currently calling it, in this case you are doing it in a worker thread, however by calling `h.sendMessage(h.obtainMessage());` you are forcing the handler to use the thread where it is attached to execute handleMessage, in your case the MAIN thread...

Regards!

Comment: i am aware of it .i am trying to use to see why dispatchMessage is not able to run the method.i am trying to print and show the difference in thread name when running sendmessage and dispatchmessage.

Comment: you can't call Toast.makeText from a worker Thread, thats why im trying to say, if you want to see the Thread names do not use Toast, use android.util.Log.d("YourTag", "Thread Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName())...

Comment: thanks .but the error that comes is related to some looper class .